# weather api key is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working with Open Weather API, but when i send an request for a city data, i get network error.

Here is the action which does the job of getting the resource.

**actions/index.js**

```
import axios from "axios";


const ROOT_URL = `https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}`;

export const FETCH_WEATHER = "FETCH_WEATHER";

export function fetchWeather(city) {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  console.log("request:", request);

  return {
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

When i press the submit button then i can see error in the mozilla firefox console.
something like this...**Error:network error**

[image: error]

but i want the city name under the city header...
just like this...
[image]

Comment: Are you running tests on a localhost?

Comment: yes on localhost

Answer (score 3):

axios.get(url) is returning promise,
conventional way is,

```
export function fetchWeather(city) {

    const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
    const res = axios.get(url).then(function(res){
    console.log("response:", res);

       return {
         type: FETCH_WEATHER,
         payload: res
        };
     }).catch(err){
      console.log(err)
     }
}
```

**OR**,

Use async/await to get required result.

```
export async function fetchWeather(city) {
  try{
    const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
    const res = await axios.get(url);

    console.log("request:", res);

    return {
      type: FETCH_WEATHER,
      payload: res
    };
  }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
   }
}
```

Comment: I have added  try catch, can you catch the err in console and let us know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You have built your URL wrong way, and you can not query your initial URL, it is just a sample ready for download.

```
import axios from 'axios';


const ROOT_URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast';

export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';

export function fetchWeather(city) {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}?q=${city},us&APPID=${API_KEY}`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  console.log('request:', request);

  return {
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In your **actions/index.js** put this:

```
import axios from "axios";

    const API_KEY = "YOUR API KEY GOES HERE ...";
    const ROOT_URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`;

    export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';

    export function fetchWeather(city) {
      const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city}`;

      const request = axios.get(url);

      return {
        type: FETCH_WEATHER,
        payload: request,
      };
    }
```

---

In your **reducers/reducer_weather.js** put this:

```
import { FETCH_WEATHER } from "../actions/index";

export default function (state = [], action) {
  if (action.error) {
  return state;
  }
  switch (action.type) {
  case FETCH_WEATHER:
  return [action.payload.data, ...state];
  }

  return state;
  }
```

Additionally, make sure to include your *`weather reducer`* inside of you root reducer, for example:

---

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import WeatherReducer from "./reducer_weather";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  weather: WeatherReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Thanks for giving time,but i had already added weather_reducer in my project..and i have tried your code into my project...but nothing gonna happen

Comment: Give this a shot. if it helps you, accept my answer, if not, then, I really can't help you further. It's my GitHub repo. I think it's the exact same project :)

https://github.com/BiggaHD/Reactive-Weather

Cheers.